# Why is mechanize throwing a HTTP 403 error?

Tags: python, http-headers, mechanize

For some reason I get a `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` when I try opening the page `http://questionablecontent.net`. I used to get a `robots.txt` error, but that has been solved. Additionally, I can't even find their robots.txt file.

I can still view the webpage from chrome, so what I'm wondering is: does mechanize look differently than chrome even after setting the appropriate headers?

Here is my code (which does not work):

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
```

I also tried setting the addheaders to the same headers as my browser (which I found [here](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/)):

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36')]
```

... but that didn't work either.

Finally, I tried using Selenium and that worked, seeing as it loads the page in chrome and then communicates with Python. However, I still would like to get it working with mechanize. Also, I'm still unsure as to how chrome and mechanize look different to their server.

Comment: your question really help me and solved my problem! thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is probably in the request headers selenium is sending, apart from the user agent header, some servers check other headers as well to ensure a real browser is talking to them. look at one of my older answers:

[urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/13303773#13303773)

In your place, I would try adding all the headers your real chrome browser sends, and then eliminate the unnecessary ones.

Comment: It's strange, I stopped getting the 403 error without changing my code. Though I used this same code on their website and it used to work, so I'm going to assume something was changing on their end. I've gone and added the additional headers just in case regardless.

Comment: For clarity, if I were send all of the headers that my real chrome browser sends, would it look exactly the same as if my chrome browser was sending the request? Is there anything else going on?

Comment: If you send all the received cookies back, and all the headers that a real browser sends, it will look the same surely. The only thing that can make a difference is javascript. Pages that are heavily ajax based often do some data / cookie modifications on the client side before sending a request, and it might be harder to "reverse engineer" and emulate that behavior with raw requests. In those cases it's better to use a webdriver, like selenium, or write one from scratch using PySide/PyQt's QtWebKit module for instance.