# Python (Post) submit a form

Tags: python, post, submit

I am teaching myself with submitting a form on the web

but somehow post is not working.

The url is https://courselist.wm.edu/courselist/

and the code so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
import re

url = 'http://courselist.wm.edu/courselist'
with requests.Session() as session:

   response = session.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

   data = {
      'term_code' : '201530',
      'term_subj' : 'AFST',
      'attr' : '0',
      'levl' : '0',
      'status' : '0'
   }

   r = session.post(url, data=data)

   #response = session.post(url, data=data)
   print r.content
   #soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

   #for row in soup.select('table'):
     # print [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot submit a form with **Beautifulsoup**. For this you should use [**Mechanize**](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). See [here](http://toddhayton.com/2014/12/08/form-handling-with-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/) an example of how to use it for form submitting.

Comment: I tried br.open('website..') and this error pops up. Is the website blocked openning to prevent robot?         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "course.py", line 11, in <module>
    br.open('http://courselist.wm.edu/courselist')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096885/python-mechanize-request-disallowed-by-robots-txt-even-after-set-handle-robot) answer and the one it links to.