# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Tunnel or SSL Forbidden>

Tags: python, urllib2

Basically ,I'm trying to use python's `urllib2`. I want to connect and fetch the data from a site. The problem is that I get the error

`urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Tunnel or SSL Forbidden>`

After repeating my experiments with this library , I found that the code I had written worked well with **https://** sites but not with **http://** sites. I read a few earlier questions on stack overflow suggesting to add the header `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7` (to spoof the header).

I did that but still it failed.

After that I read this [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

I tried that as well but that didn't work.

Here's my code

```
import urllib2
url = "http://the_site_i_want_to_connect"
hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7','Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
req = urllib2.Request(url , headers=hdr)
p = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print p
```

PS: As I said , this works fine with **https**

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what site are you trying to access? I would also recommend using requests

Comment: Tried a few sites with http:// for eg. http://www.nseindia.com

Comment: where are you running it from? FWIW I cannot replicate.  try `import requests;requests.get(url)` if you have requests installed.

Comment: running it in the ubuntu terminal

Comment: did you try using requests?

Comment: yep , but it shows the same problem. Basically , I need help to understand the reason behind the error. 
PS: the error message `requests.exceptions.ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Tunnel or SSL Forbidden.`

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes , i am under the proxy settings of my institute

Comment: Have you tried setting `proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}` and `requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)`, replacing with appropriate values?

Comment: yes , proxy was the real culrprit! Thanks for the help Padriac! (Also tried adding proxy settings to urllib2. That worked as well!)

Comment: Any reason why it works correctly fir https without proxy?

Comment: Not sure really, must have something to do with how the proxy is set up

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please consider adding as answer. I came across this problem and almost miss your answer

Answer (score 4):

This error looks like issue with your proxy settings please refer this [blog](https://kktechinnovation.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/proxy-tunneling-failed-forbiddenunable-to-establish-ssl-connection/)