# BeautifulSoup get <cite> tags from Google

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm making a Python script that searches for a term on [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=shakespeare+pdf) and gets PDF links only.

I am trying to grab the "green" search results that are marked with `<cite>`. They are not links, only titles.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=shakespeare+pdf"
get = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get)

pdf = re.compile(r"\.(pdf)")

cite_pdfs = soup.find_all(pdf, class_="_Rm")
print cite_pdfs
```

However, the list only returns `[]` i.e. nothing.

Comment: Why are you passing in a regular expression matching `.pdf` in as the *element name*? `.find_all()` filters on single elements, not on context.

Comment: Agreed with Matijn, you can also use the filter `soup.findAll('cite' , attrs={'class':'Rm'})` for more specific information.

Comment: @OsamahAl-Ghammari Thanks, I tried that but doesn't return anything. Even if I take the `pdf` regex out of the line and look for `"cite"` or `"_Rm"` I get `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good implementation for it.I used [hdr request from urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden) in order to passby `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

site= "http://www.google.com/search?q=shakespeare+pdf"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    ka=soup.findAll('cite',attrs={'class':'_Rm'})
    for i in ka:
        print i.text
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()
```

and here are the results,

```
davidlucking.com/documents/Shakespeare-Complete%20Works.pdf
www.artsvivants.ca/pdf/.../shakespeare_overvie...
www.folgerdigitaltexts.org/PDF/Ham.pdf
sparks.eserver.org/.../shakespeare-tempest.pdf
manybooks.net/.../shakespeetext94shaks12.htm...
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.adweek.com/.../free...shakespeare.../1868...
www.goodreads.com/ebooks/.../1420.Hamlet
calhoun.k12.il.us/teachers/wdeffenbaugh/.../Shakespeare%20Sonnets.pdf
www.freeclassicebooks.com/william_shakespea...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this implementation! Will links be written in full if I export to csv, i.e. is the `/.../` just when printing in a terminal?

Comment: @Winterflags I had a similar problem with the `cite` tag see this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638286/how-to-return-the-full-link-from-the-cite-tag-in-a-google-search-request)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  if result.select_one('.ZGwO7'):
    pdf_file = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Also, it might be because there was no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified because the default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into HTTP request headers.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-scrape-and-download-PDF-files-locally#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "best lasagna recipe:pdf"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # check if PDF is present via according CSS class
  if result.select_one('.ZGwO7'):
    pdf_file = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
    print(pdf_file)

---------
'''
http://www.bakersedge.com/PDF/Lasagna.pdf
http://greatgreens.ca/recipes/Recipe%20-%20Worlds%20Best%20Lasagna.pdf
https://liparifoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lipari-foods-holiday-recipes.pdf
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Search Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that it allows you to get the data fast, not creating a parser from scratch, and maintain it over time.

Code to integrate to achieve your goal:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "best lasagna recipe:pdf",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result results['organic_results']:
  if '.pdf' in result['link']:
    pdf_file = result['link']
    print(pdf_file)

---------
'''
http://www.bakersedge.com/PDF/Lasagna.pdf
http://greatgreens.ca/recipes/Recipe%20-%20Worlds%20Best%20Lasagna.pdf
https://liparifoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lipari-foods-holiday-recipes.pdf
...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more in-depth blog post about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.