# How to return the full link from the cite tag in a google search request

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am successfully running this script below that returns a list of search links based on the `cite` tag.  Unfortunately some of the returned links are condensed. For example: `www.intel.com/.../i-o-controller-hub-8-9-10-82566-82567-82562v-software- dev-manual.pdf`.  Is there a way to return the full link?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = []
num_pages = 2

search_query = 'algorithm+encoding+desirable+character+signal+64-bit+communication+binary+propert'

for start in range(0, num_pages):
    url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+ search_query + '&start=' + str(start*num_pages)

    page = opener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    for cite in soup.findAll('cite'):
         print(cite.text)
```

Is there a setting, or better method to get search links from google?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of searching through the `<cite>` elements, how about you grab all of the `<h3>`s with the class `r`. Then you can grab the `<a>` tag inside of that, and get the anchor's href, like this:

```
for link in soup.find_all('h3', class_='r'):
    print(link.a['href'][7:])
```

The splicing (`[7:]`) is because every url starts with `/url?q=` so google can track them. Your final solution would look like this

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = []
num_pages = 2

search_query = 'algorithm+encoding+desirable+character+signal+64-bit+communication+binary+propert'

for start in range(0, num_pages):
    url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+ search_query + '&start=' + str(start*num_pages)

    page = opener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('h3', class_='r'):
        print(link.a['href'][7:])

        text = link.a['href'][7:]
        head, sep, tail = text.partition('&sa')
        print(head)
```

Comment: Perfect! I added text.partition to get the clean link.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh good catch, I didn't even notice that there was another query param.

Answer (score 0):

Code from [wpercy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41640035/15164646) doesn't work anymore because of `CSS` selectors changes in the HTML.

To grab the full link, you're looking for this since you don't need to do slicing:

```py
# container with needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # extracting link from container above
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) because, for example, default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "algorithm+encoding+desirable+character+signal+64-bit+communication+binary+property",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(title, link, sep='\n')

-----------
'''
Gray code - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code
An Introduction to Arithmetic Coding
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10704/Intro_Arith_coding.pdf
Chapter 3 Digital Transmission Fundamentals
http://www.sfu.ca/~ljilja/ENSC427/Spring16/News/Leon-Garcia_Widjaja/LGW2EChapter3Presentation.pdf
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](http://algorithm+encoding+desirable+character+signal+64-bit+communication+binary+property) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with such problems since it's done for the end-user, and pretty much the only thing that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "algorithm+encoding+desirable+character+signal+64-bit+communication+binary+property",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()


for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])

-----------
'''
Gray code - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code
An Introduction to Arithmetic Coding
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10704/Intro_Arith_coding.pdf
Chapter 3 Digital Transmission Fundamentals
http://www.sfu.ca/~ljilja/ENSC427/Spring16/News/Leon-Garcia_Widjaja/LGW2EChapter3Presentation.pdf
...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.