# Python Program with urllib Module

Tags: python

Folks

Below program is for finding out the IP address given in the page http://whatismyipaddress.com/

```
import urllib2
import re

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://whatismyipaddress.com/')

p = response.readlines()
for line in p:
    ip = re.findall(r'(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)',line)
    print ip
```

But I am not able to trouble shoot the issue as it was giving below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 5, in <module>
  response = urllib2.urlopen('http://whatismyipaddress.com/')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

anyone have any idea what change is required to remove the errors and get the required output?

Comment: They are checking the "User-Agent" header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The http error code `403` tells you that the server does not want to respond to your request for some reason. In this case, I think it is the user agent of your query (the default used by urllib2).

You can change the user agent:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://www.whatismyipaddress.com/')
```

Then your query will work.

But there is no guarantee that this will keep working. The site could decide to block automated queries.

Comment: Seems they are using a blacklist. 'wget' is blocked, but 'w' gets through :)

Comment: @chris it worked... it provided the output... can u explain what exaclty the 1st and 2nd line of ur code does?

Comment: @chris,                                                                                                                    p = response.readlines()

for line in p:

    IP = re.finditer(r'(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)',line)

print IP

Comment: @chris added above lines to the code u have given..but still not giving the required output.instead it gives  <callable-iterator object at 0x102a92d50>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import re
>>> site= 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/'
>>> hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
...        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
...        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
...        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
...        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
...        'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
>>> req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> p = response.readlines()
>>> for line in p:
...     ip = re.findall(r'(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)',line)
...     print ip
```

[urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `requests` package [here](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), instead of the `urllib2`

it is much easier to use :

```
import requests
url='http://whereismyip.com'
header = {'user-Agent':'curl/7.21.3'}
r= requests.get(url,header)
```

you can use curl as the user-Agent

Comment: installed the module requests.and tried to execute below code                                                                                                  import requests

r = requests.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com/')

print r.text

but there is no response for this code

Comment: @Maverick the url should be a valid url with proper protocol defined, in this case   you should provide it with `the http://' `  Try use  `url = 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/'`  then `r = requests.get(url) ` if you need to custom header you can pass the header to the get method like `headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}  r=requests.get(url,headers)`