# python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am really an ETL guy trying to learn Python, please help

```
import urllib2
urls =urllib2.urlopen("url1","url2")
i=0
while i< len(urls):
  htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(urls[i])
  htmltext = htmlfile.read()
  print htmltext
  i+=1
```

I am getting errors as

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File ".\test.py", line 2, in 
>   urls =urllib2.urlopen("url1","url2")
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
>   response = meth(req, response)
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
>   'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
>   return self._call_chain(*args)
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>   result = func(*args)
>   File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Comment: Isn't the error you get obvious?

Comment: Hi ozgur, i know very little basics of python .. can brief more please ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is coming from line 2:

`urls =urllib2.urlopen("url1","url2")`

Whatever url you're trying to access is returning a http error code

`HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed`

Looking at the urllib2 docs, you should only be using 1 url as an argument

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html
>
> Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.
>
> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided.

The 2nd argument you're putting in may be turning the request into a POST, which would explain the Method Not Allowed code.