# Python 3.5 urllib.request 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib, http-status-code-403

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

print(soup.title)
```

**I was trying to go to the above site and the code keeps spitting out a 403 Forbidden Error.**

Any Ideas?

> C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:/Users/jerem/PycharmProjects/webscraper/url scraper.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/jerem/PycharmProjects/webscraper/url scraper.py", line 7, in 
>       page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.title)
```

out:

```
<title>BrightScope Ratings</title>
```

First, use `requests` rather than `urllib`.

Than, add `headers` to `requests`, if not,  the site will ban your, because the default `User-Agent` is crawler, which the site do not like.

Comment: Can you explain why you suggest to use `requests` instead of `urllib`? And what about `urllib2` ?