# Python HTTP request with headers attached generates 403 error on cloud server, running fine on my machine

Tags: python, server, httprequest, http-status-code-403

To wrap up the issue I found and need help on,

- I created a python program that calls a get request from
  https://bx.in.th/api/pairing/
- The program works well on my machine (Mac OSX)
- Once running on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet, it throws HTTP 403
  forbidden error.
- I did a day of research and most of the answers are to modify headers
  which I tried them all with no light of success.

Some links/references I went through.

- [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden?rq=1)
- [Python 3.5 urllib.request 403 Forbidden Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214965/python-3-5-urllib-request-403-forbidden-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [HTTP error 403 in Python 3 Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping)

Here is the simplified source code that points to the problem :

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://bx.in.th/api/pairing/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
print()
print(response.getheaders())
```

The proper output should be :

```
b'{"1":{"pairing_id":1,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"BTC"},"21":{"pairing_id":21,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"ETH"},"22":{"pairing_id":22,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"DAS"},"23":{"pairing_id":23,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"REP"},"20":{"pairing_id":20,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"ETH"},"4":{"pairing_id":4,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"DOG"},"6":{"pairing_id":6,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"FTC"},"24":{"pairing_id":24,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"GNO"},"13":{"pairing_id":13,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"HYP"},"2":{"pairing_id":2,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"LTC"},"3":{"pairing_id":3,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"NMC"},"26":{"pairing_id":26,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"OMG"},"14":{"pairing_id":14,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"PND"},"5":{"pairing_id":5,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"PPC"},"19":{"pairing_id":19,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"QRK"},"15":{"pairing_id":15,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"XCN"},"7":{"pairing_id":7,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"XPM"},"17":{"pairing_id":17,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"XPY"},"25":{"pairing_id":25,"primary_currency":"THB","secondary_currency":"XRP"},"8":{"pairing_id":8,"primary_currency":"BTC","secondary_currency":"ZEC"}}'

[('Date', 'Sun, 13 Aug 2017 09:27:02 GMT'), ('Content-Type', 'text/javascript'), ('Content-Length', '1485'), ('Connection', 'close'), ('Set-Cookie', '__cfduid=d51c37ea835bae4a0c892e91f34f7bc131502616422; expires=Mon, 13-Aug-18 09:27:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.bx.in.th; HttpOnly'), ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400'), ('Expires', 'Mon, 14 Aug 2017 09:27:02 GMT'), ('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=0'), ('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'), ('Server', 'cloudflare-nginx'), ('CF-RAY', '38daa2e36e0a836b-BKK')]
```

The error got from running the source code on the droplet :

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "api-call.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Thank you!

Comment: It may be blocking the digitalocean's ip

Comment: Is there a body attached to the response? Catch the exception, you can use `.read()` on it to get the response body. It may be the server included more detail as to why it responded with a 403.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would you do that?

Comment: Run `curl https://bx.in.th/api/pairing/` on your server to see if they are  blocking your IP range.

Comment: @t.m.adam: handling exceptions you mean? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would you read the response?  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @t.m.adam: I already told you; catch the exception; the exception object has a `.read()` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for clarifying. I thought you meant `read()` the response.

Comment: @t.m.adam: the exception object represents the response.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, got it now

Comment: @Himal I tried running the command and then I got HTML page(in text) without error.

Comment: @TawanThampipattanakul You meant a `text/javascript` response ? You could use `curl -I https://bx.in.th/api/pairing/` to get the headers only so you can see the HTTP status code.

Comment: I followed your suggestion @MartijnPieters and retrieved HTML bytes from exceptionObject.read(). then I got following page : 

Please enable cookies.
One more step

Please complete the security check to access bx.in.th

Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?

Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.

...

Cloudflare Ray ID: 38db27a5582c6fcc • Your IP: 128.1XX.XX.XX • Performance & security by Cloudflare

Comment: @TawanThampipattanakul: so they are using cloudflare to protect their site and digital ocean's IP address is subject to extra checks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so... is this considered as impossible?

Comment: @TawanThampipattanakul: Cloudflare certainly tries to make it impossible; perhaps you need to respect the restrictions that the site admins have put in place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know the reason. bx.in.th is currently attacked by DDOS frequently, so I believe they setup a restriction against DO droplets' IP since it is low cost and efficient for the attack.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help :)
To summarize, the API i want to access uses CloudFlare to block DO IPs for security reasons so I decided to use another cloud provider instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use strong proxy like Luminati.
I also was getting 403 error status, but it works well with luminati proxy.

Comment: My apology, I somehow missed this answer. Just want to confirm that when I ran into this same problem few years after I opened this question, a friend suggested and I tried luminati proxy which worked pretty well for me.

Comment: k, sounds good. hope you are going well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on Digital Ocean

Solution is to sign up for a proxy and use it.  Note: luminiti is now brightdata.com

Example from them below.

I suggest using Python's requests module and then setting your call like this:

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': 'http://brd-customer-hl_234567a0-zone-isp:0123456789ab@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225',
           'https': 'http://brd-customer-hl_234567a0-zone-isp:0123456789ab@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225'}
url = 'https://bx.in.th/api/pairing/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 etc'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)

r.status_code # should be 200, not 403
```

Use `r.text` or `r.json()` to read the api data from the request object.

Actually, you only need the https proxy for this example but it's good practice to include them both.