# Urllib2 not working, http forbidden error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the yts api, and I wrote the following code.

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json?quality=3D'

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

But I ran into the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Help me how to fix this

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what's going on with your urllib2 request, as it works fine with the other urls I tested, with and without JSON responses.

I suspect it's an encoding thing for the quality=3D query, but my brief attempt at handling that also failed.

Simply putting the request in a browser works, as does the following 'requests' code.

In a nutshell, I'm not truly answering your question regarding fixing the urllib2 usage, but definitely fixing the problem of getting the data.

I'd suggest working with the 'requests' module in this case. Try

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json?quality=3D'

response = requests.get( url = url )

data = response.json()

print data
```

Note that the requests response.json() handles the json.load() for you.

It will save you many a headache over urllib2.

The 'requests' documentation:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/