# Iterating through many json links, but encountering a jsondecode error

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have a this JSON that contains information from many "videos". Within every single "video" in the JSON is another link to a new JSON that contains "messages".

I am trying to iterate through the "message" JSON links and insert them to a MongoDB database.

The problem is that I get a JSONDecodeError. What am I doing wrong and how do I make it right?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/import_messages_dev.py", line 35, in 
>       raw_messages_data = requests.get(url3).json()
>
> File "venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
>       return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 354, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 380)

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import pymongo

###  DATABASE ####
# Connect to database // login user:password
uri = 'mongodb://testuser:password@ds245687.mlab.com:45687/liveme'
# Set client.
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
# Set database.
db = client.get_database()

# Create collection.
messages = db['messages']

# The url to the live.me replays.
replay_url = "http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?"

userid = 895324164037541888

# Parsing the urls for replays and profile with the userid.
url2 = replay_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({'userid': userid}) + '&page_size=1000'

# Printing urls for own validation.
print(f"Replay url: {url2}\n")

# Pull the data from replay json.
raw_replay_data = requests.get(url2).json()

print("Message links: ")

# Insert messages to database.
for i in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    url3 = i['msgfile']
    raw_messages_data = requests.get(url3).json()
    messages.insert_many(raw_messages_data)

    print(url3)

client.close()
```

**Update for further help to the answer**

So to iterate and get all the links, read it line by line and parse it as JSON and insert it to database I'm trying to do it like this, but it create a new error.

```
for i in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    url3 = i['msgfile']
    raw_message_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)
    for line in raw_message_data:
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        messages.insert_many(json_data)
```

The new error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/import_messages_dev.py", line 54, in <module>
    raw_message_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url3` which may contain this value:
http://s.live.ksmobile.net/cheetahlive/20/7e/15204559238152116852/15204559238152116852.json

contains individual dictionaries but the entire file is not stored as a JSON array.

Structure is like:

```
   { "channelType":"TEMPGROUP", ... } # line 1
   { "channelType":"TEMPGROUP", ... } # line 2
```

So need to read it by line and parse each line as JSON.

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)

for line in response:
    json_data = json.loads(line)
    # Do something with json_data
```

Comment: So to iterate and get all the links, read it line by line and parse it as JSON and insert it to database I'm trying to do it like this, but it create a new error.
`for i in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    url3 = i['msgfile']    
    raw_message_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)
    for line in raw_message_data:
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        messages.insert_many(json_data)`

Comment: I have updated my original question for better formatting.

Comment: I have put it at the end of the original question.

Comment: @aquatic7, add a `User-Agent` header to the urlopen request

Comment: @aquatic7, does it work now? for your reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden

Comment: No, I don't know what to do. How or where to add the header. :(

Comment: @aquatic7, everything is there. you just need to read and understand it. you can't just copy-paste code all your life

Comment: I'm not copy/pasting code all my life. I do a lot of time reading, learning, trying, failing, trying, failing, understanding. But sometimes to see the final result makes it easier to deduct and learn from it, by seeing how it works and use it for future reference when similar problems occur. But I will use the information you have provided me and read some more about the use of headers. Thank you very much for your help so far. Much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166432/discussion-between-aquatic7-and-codekaizer).