# python fill an html form

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I need to fill a form of an HTML to then scrap the results from this.
I've got the following code (python 3.6)

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.situacaocadastral.com.br"
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'doc': 3984782000139}).encode("utf-8")
results=urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)

print(results.read())
```

From inspection I know that the form name is 'doc' and I'm trying to pass the query 3984782000139.

At this stage I'm getting the following error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you consider strange about the error?

Comment: Don't know. Should I spoof as a browser?

Comment: We don't know either. It either boils down to you not sending the correct headers or not supplying credentials to authenticate your request

Comment: Please have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)