# Why there is an urllib error for some website

Tags: python, open-source, project

I don't know where to start. I would like to create an price alert using python.(when is lower than X $ for example)

But when i try to read some website (like `https://www.gearbest.com`) i got

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

But works with `https://amazon.com`

What is the easiest way to retrieve few info on a webpage list?

I would like to be able to follow the price evolution.

Comment: Try adding headers while requesting as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)!

Comment: This work for you ? Because not for me. i got this error : TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind any Firewall? Did you ensure that?