# urlopen of urllib.request cannot open a page in python 3.7

Tags: python, urllib

I want to write webscraper to collect titles of articles from Medium.com webpage.

I am trying to write a python script that will **scrape** headlines from Medium.com website. I am using python 3.7 and imported `urlopen` from `urllib.request`.
But it cannot open the site and shows

```
 "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" error.
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import  urlopen

webAdd = urlopen("https://medium.com/")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(webAdd.read())
```

```
Result = urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Expected result is that it will not show any error and just read the web site.

But this does not happen when I use requests module.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = 'https://medium.com/' 
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
```

This time around it works without error.

Why ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Urllib is pretty old and small module. For webscraping, `requests` module is recommended. 
[You can check out this answer for additional information.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2018026/7515189)

Answer (score 3):

Many sites nowadays check where the user agent is coming from, to try and deter bots.  `requests` is the better module to use, but if you really want to use `urllib`, you can alter the headers text, to pretend to be Firefox or something else, so that it is not blocked.  Quick example can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187955

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion'

url = "http://example.com"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

You will need to alter the user_agent string with the appropriate versions of things too.  Hope this helps.

Comment: As a note, it seems like you don't need to necessarily fake out a browser's user agent. Just doing `request.add_header('User-Agent', 'my app name')` appears to work for medium.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Would you guys tell me how did you all learn about all these! Is there a book? This is so next level code!!!

Comment: It comes with practice. Pretty soon you will encounter dynamic sites which require you to render Javascript. `Selenium` is a webdriver you could use to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
import urllib 
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen(MY_URL)
contents = html.read()
print(contents)
```