# How to fix HTTPError: Forbidden in urllib/urlopen

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib, spyder, urlopen

I have just started learning python recently, although I do have some previous coding experience.

I am trying to scrape something from a website using BeautifulSoup and keep getting an error. I realise this question has been posted before, but I was unsure how to implement the solutions..

Here is my code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
```

The error message I get is:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Forbidden
```

Supposedly, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187955) fixes the problem, but I was unsure how to actually code it and what my entire modified script should look like.

Could someone tell me how I would amend my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to try setting up a known browser user agent with the Request method:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'
req=Request(my_url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(req)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's much more easier to implement than some of the other solutions I had a look at.

My main goal was to try and get the text from the links that go to "X Full quotes by XXXX"

Would you know how to proceed forward?

Answer (score 0):

Use requests. It is much better as it does all the heavy work (urllib) for you:

```py
# pip install requests

from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'

s = Session()

r = s.get(my_url)

# get soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

print(soup.prettify())
```